# How to use yield with multistatement for?

Tags: scala, for-loop, yield

*The code is just for illustrative purposes, i.e. it is an **example** not a real code.*

I tried this:

```
val results = for(i <- 1 to 20)
{
  val x = i+1
  println(x)
  yield x
}
```

and this

```
val results = for {i <- 1 to 20;
  val x = i+1;
  println(x)
}
  yield x
```

But none of this works -- I need a generator, definition, and **a statement** -- is this possible to do it with yield? If yes, what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hopefully, this will get you started:

```
  val result = for (i <- 1 to 10 if i%2==0) yield {
     println(i); 
     i
  }
```

which is equivalent to

```
 (1 to 10).filter(_%2==0).map(x => { println(x); x } )
```

Comment: Great, I didn't know yield could be a block with resulting expression.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to think that `for` in Scala is similar to `for` in imperative languages. It's not! Behind the scenes, it makes use of `flatMap`. Every expression in the first section of the `for/yield` syntax must have a certain form. If I'm not mistaken, it must either be an assignment (restricted to `val`, maybe) or a `<-` expression. You can hack it to get what you want:

```
for {
  i <- 1 to 20
  val x = i + 1
  _ <- {println(x); List(1)}
} yield x
```

But that is pretty horrible. Hacking the `yield`, as Jamil demonstrated, is also a possibility, though also pretty horrible.

The question is, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? `foreach` is best used for side-effecting loop code:

```
(1 to 10) foreach { i =>
  val x = i+1
  println(x)
}
```

`map` is best used for producing a new list of the same length:

```
(1 to 10) map (i => i + 1)
```

It is rather unusual, and somewhat ugly, to want to do both at the same time.

Comment: Thank you, but note 2 things. With foreach you didn't get any results, and with map you didn't get any statement (it is fixable though). What I try to accomplish? It depends on the task -- it simplifies to this trio: generator+definition+statement, resulting with new sequence. The problem is the elegance -- for me, for is more elegant that map, and that is why I try to use for+yield.

Comment: @macias You could have two traversals. I think that's more elegant but might be less efficient. But since you're printing, I don't think this matters here.

Comment: @macias "for me, for is more elegant than map"; I presume this is because of prior experience with Java or C? If you want to learn the FP way of doing things (which Scala encourages), you'll need to try to embrace map, filter, and fold, and avoid side-effecting code.